# Riverpod - StreamProvider.value is null from inside another provider

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have a provider that provides a class called CurrentUserService that exposes a stream called user$. I also have a StreamProvider that just exposes that stream. I have verified that the stream has had a user value added to it, and then after that, I try to access the value from inside another provider, and it says the value is null. The 2 providers:

```
/// Current user service
final currentUserServiceProvider = Provider<CurrentUserService>((ref) {
  return CurrentUserService(
    authRepo: ref.read(authRepoProvider),
  );
});

/// Current user
final userProvider = StreamProvider<VpUser>((ref) {
  return ref.watch(currentUserServiceProvider).user$;
});
```

Here's a screenshot showing it is populated:

[image]

Then after that code has executed, I'm reading the value of user (using watch) from another provider and getting null:

[image]

Any idea why the user is null when it shouldn't be?

EDIT here is some more code:

CurrentUserService:

```
/// This service holds the current user.
class CurrentUserService {
  Stream<VpUser> user$ = const Stream.empty();
  StreamSubscription<User?>? _fireBaseUserSubscription;
  final _userStreamController = BehaviorSubject<VpUser>();

  CurrentUserService({required AuthRepo authRepo}) {
    user$ = _userStreamController.stream;
  }

  Future<VpLocation> determinePosition() async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;

    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
    }

    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
      }
    }

    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      return Future.error(
        'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.',
      );
    }
    final pos = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();

    return VpLocation(lat: pos.latitude, lng: pos.longitude);
  }

  void onDestroy() {
    _fireBaseUserSubscription?.cancel();
    _userStreamController.close();
  }

  void updateUser(VpUser user) {
    _userStreamController.add(user);
  }
}
```

It might be a timing issue, accessing the provider too soon after the value is added to the stream, since it only happens once and starts working very soon after.

Comment: Your thin ice is `ref.read` in providers where `ref.watch` is used. There is no problem using `ref.watch` and knowing that (supposedly) the provider should never be rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what's happening without the full code.
I believe this is a more intuitive way to use provider.
Hope this helps.

```
/// This class will be responsible to provide a current user to all app.
/// The changeNotifier makes this class listenable.
class CurrentUserService with ChangeNotifier {
  /// Default Constructor.
  CurrentUserService({required this.autoRepo}) {
  // Start listening to your stream in the class initializer.
  _load();
  }

  // Fix the type.
  final Object autoRepo;

  /// Store Subscription to vpUserStream.
  StreamSubscription<VpUser> _vpUserSub

  /// Store current [VpUser] privately.
  VpUser? _vpUser
  VpUser? get vpUser;
  set vpUser(VpUser? value) {
    // Ensure the class is prepared to be compared like that.
    // Otherwise create a "isEqual" method.
    if(value == _vpUser) return;
    _vpUser = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// Point to the stream of [VpUser] you have already.
  Stream<VpUser> get vpUserStream;

  void _load() => _vpUserSub = vpUserStream.listen((event) => vpUser = event);
  void _unload() => _vpUserSub.cancel();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _unload();
    super.dispose();
  }
}


class InitializeApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const InitializeApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(providers: [
      // Add other controllers / providers you might need in your app.
      // The ChangeNotifierProvider will dispose the classes it creates.
      // If you decide to instantiate your class and provide only it's value,
      // make sure to dispose it yourself.
     ChangeNotifierProvider(create: CurrentUserService(autoRepo: '')),
     ],
     child: const MyApp(),
     );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // If you use a select or watch, this builder will get rebuilt  everytime
    // your provider sends a notification.
    final user = context.select((CurrentUserService service) => service.vpUser);
    return Text('$user');
  }
}
// In case you want to use listen to it in another class (not in a widget).
class MyAppController with ChangeNotifier {
  MyAppController(this.currentUserService) {
    currentUserService.addListener(_handleUserUpdate);
  }
  final CurrentUserService currentUserService;

  void _handleUserUpdate() {
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    currentUserService.removeListener(_handleUserUpdate);
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind the OP was asking about riverpod, which can mimic provider, but has newer tools for most things with a better overall design.